# My query for counting subrecords in Acces does not work?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem with my query. I'm having a database with a Table "Label" that contains some subrecords("ReleaseID").

What I want to do: I want to count the subrecords that are linked to the LabelID in my Label table. I have the following code:

```
Dim db As Object
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim qryCount As String
    Dim Value as integer

qryCount = "select count(ReleaseID) as aantal from(select LabelID, ReleaseID from Label where LabelID = " & Me!LabelID")


    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(qryCount, dbOpenDynaset)
    Value = rst!aantal
```

The query is working when I try it in the Query design in Acces. But when I use it in VBA then it doesn't.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in your VB code, and your query is open to SQL injection in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Closing parenthesis was a copy mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see your actual code when you don't format it.

This is what you last posted

```
qryCount = "select count(ReleaseID) as aantal from Label where LabelID = " & Me!LabelID 
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Label", dbOpenDynaset) 
Value = rst1!aantal
```

If that's what you actually have then you

> 1. Probably can't use Value - I think that's a reserved word
> 2. You've set the recordset name to rst but you're trying to use rst1 for value reference

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if its just a copy mistake, but the closing brace is missing, isn't it?

```
qryCount = "select count(ReleaseID) as aantal from(select LabelID, ReleaseID from Label where LabelID = " & Me!LabelID & ")"
```

Comment: Sorry, indeed a copy mistake.

Comment: How about directly querying the table with `"select count(ReleaseID) as aantal from Label where LabelID = " & Me!LabelID`? Does this query not return your desired result?

Comment: Run-time error '3061':

Too few parameters. Expected: 1.

Comment: I do not have much experience with Access (but with SQL itself) ...
Does your code look like `...
select count(ReleaseID) as aantal from Label where LabelID = " & Me!LabelID

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(qryCount, dbOpenDynaset)
Value = rst!aantal` ?

Comment: Ok I fixed that error. Following comes up:

Runtime error '3265':

Item not found in this collection

Comment: Code looks like this now:

qryCount = "select count(ReleaseID) as aantal from Label where LabelID = " & Me!LabelID
    

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Label", dbOpenDynaset)
Value = rst1!aantal

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help anymore, because I'm not familiar with the API/with VBA... I assumed the query is not well designed (why I tried answering your question...). Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If your are just looking for a count you can do it with DCount

```
varCount = DCount("ReleaseID", "Label", "LabelID = " & Me!LabelID)
```

No recordsets required.  If you're not iterating through the recordset Dcount is much simpler and less taxing on the system.

It's called a domain function, well worth looking up if you have a spare moment (Dlookup, DSum, Dmax, Dcount).

Comment: Doesn't work. It only counts how much LabelID there are, not how many ReleaseID that are linked to that LabelID.

Comment: I can't see how.....  Is there another table in play that Label is joined to?  Can you post the table layouts?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use *DCount*:

```
Dim Value As Long
Value = DCount("*", "ReleaseTable", "[LabelID] = " & Me!LabelID.Value & "")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It only counts how much LabelID there are, not how many ReleaseID that are linked to that LabelID.

Comment: That you haven't mentioned nowhere, but see edit where it counts from your Release table. Of course, adjust the table name to your actual name.